# check if the identifier is of function or object or some literal in babel transform phase using abstract syntax tree

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree

Trying to write a plugin that does the following function pipeline:
var a = 2 | square | double;

to

var a = double(square(2));

but to make it function correctly whether the identifier to the left of the '|' operator refers to a function or an object or any literal.